# Why navigation rule is not working?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation

I want to redirect one page to another with jsf

I put this code in my `bean.java` :

```
public String retour()
{ 
    return "home";
}
```

This code in my list.xhtml page

```
 <p:commandButton value="Submit"  
   action="#{bean.retour}" 
   styleClass="ui-priority-primary" 
   process="@this" />
```

and this code in faces-config.xml

```
  <navigation-rule>
   <display-name>pages/list.xhtml</display-name>
   <from-view-id>/pages/list.xhtml</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/pages/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I put this code in web.xml page

```
<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when i push the submit button, its give me a blank page.

I tried this code and it's redirect correctly.

Can i know why the navigation rule doesn't work?

Comment: Could you try with ajax=false" on the button

Comment: could you try
action="#{bean.retour()}"

Comment: While you're using Primefaces, just get rid of the "faces-config.xml" configuration file, and put the pages' names directly in the string return statement, something like this: `return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";`.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar H'ghar thank you Jaqen it's worl with ajax=false"